# How to get ID of object from session in cucumber features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

So I'm writing acceptance features for my Shops cart actions and would like to verify that clicking the `Edit Cart` link takes me to the `edit_cart_path`.

So I have a Cucumber step definition:

```
Then(/^I should be on the (.*) page$/) do |page_name|
  current_path.should eq send(page_name.split(/\s+/).push('path').join('_').to_sym)
end
```

Which errors out on the edit page (`cart/123456/edit`) since `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"Carts"}` as my route should be `{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"Carts", :id=>123456}`

The ID of the cart is in session[:cart_id], which I can't access inside the test.

Now the question is, how do I test that I'm correctly on the edit page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to parse the ID from the URL and then pass it to the `_path` method to get verification.

Not sure if it makes any sense though...

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is designed for behavior driven development and as such the test should describe the behavior you expect to see. Rather than checking the url of the current page to make sure you have the right id, I would write the test to see if the correct content appears on the page.

So, assuming you have a cart with some items in it, something along the lines of

```
Given a cart exists
And I have added "Cucumber and Friends"
When I click the edit link
Then I should see the edit cart page
```

With the edit cart page checking that the correct content is on the page

```
page.should have_selector("h1", text: "Edit Cart")
page.should have_field("edit", with: "Cucumber and Friends")
```